# Do two images match? Using Emgu CV C#

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have two images, I need to get a return that's a bool match. Everything I'm finding is "getting the difference image" which is not what I want.

```
        Image<Gray, Byte> img1 = new Image<Gray, Byte>(imageURL);
        Image<Gray, Byte> img2 = new Image<Gray, Byte>(imageURL2);
        Image<Gray, Byte> img3 = img2 - img1;
```

I'd also take some sort of percent match return.

Answer (score 0):

[I use precisely the method described here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/domgreen/2009/09/06/comparing-two-images-in-c/).

Only thing I add is I also count different pixels so that I can have a % difference.

Comment: Sorry, I am rather newb on the C#. Can you provide a simple code example of how you accomplish this?

Comment: A code example of the % difference? Both code examples on that page provide a bool result.

Comment: @Kikootwo, I'm not sure if they changed the examples but they don't return a bool and in fact there is not one bool variable in either example. I too am looking to return a bool and tried to return true if it would draw a square but that doesn't seem to be reliable.